# Which outperforms the other?(related to string)

Tags: c#, string, performance, text, indexof

I don't know how IndexOf() method of String object works and so I would like to know which outperforms the other with the 2 following implementations:

At first, I want to introduce a little about the problem, simply, the function/method implemented here has a character as the only parameter, it should give out/return another character corresponding to the one passed in. (the rule of matching between source char collection and destination char collection is given below):

> a  <=>  9
>   b  <=>  8
>   c  <=>  7
>   d  <=>  6
>   e  <=>  5
>   f  <=>  4
>   g  <=>  3
>   h  <=>  2
>   i  <=>  1
>   j  <=>  0

Please note that, the above rule is just made for easy to follow, it's not a fixed rule, it can be any so don't base on that rule to implement those methods another way.

Now is the 2 methods I would like to compare:

## 1. The first one is very short and based on IndexOf()

```
string source = "abcdefghij";
string destination = "9876543210";
public char SourceToDest(char c){
    return destination[source.IndexOf(c)];//Suppose the c is always in source.
}
```

## 2. The second one is longer and uses switch case:

```
public char SourceToDest(char c){
  switch(c){
     case 'a': return '9';
     case 'b': return '8';
     case 'c': return '7';
     case 'd': return '6';
     case 'e': return '5';
     case 'f': return '4';
     case 'g': return '3';
     case 'h': return '2';
     case 'i': return '1';
     case 'j': return '0';
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, the rule is made for easy to follow, if not noticing this, you may have another method like this:

```
public char SourceToDest(char c){
    return (char)(154 - (int)c); //154 = 106 + 48
}
```

If you have another method which outperforms both the 2 methods I presented, please share with me.

Comment: But **what is the question**? I don't see any here.

Comment: The first line I said "...I would like to know which outperforms the other..." it's not a real question but it's some kind of expressing my want. Thanks.

Comment: I'll let someone with citations answer but:
1) This is linear (it scans the string. Not sure if there is caching. Don't think so)
2) This is O(1) (It's usually implemented with a jump table. But not sure)
3) This is also O(1) (But hard to read. It is actually an improvement over (2) in terms of pure performance because it uses less memory for the code. By that I mean that (2) compiles to having a jump table which needs to be stored in the compiled binary. (3) is just a few assembly instructions... but I don't know anything about CLR).

Comment: What keeps you from measuring yourself? Have a look at Jon Skeet's article on **[Simple Microbenchmarking in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/benchmark.html)**

Comment: @HonzaBrestan I've never measured performance myself, not enough experienced, thank you for the link :)

Comment: @HonzaBrestan While it's true that benchmarking gives you real, practical results, knowing about language implementation gives you theoretical results. It's worth mentioning that both are useful. The theoretical result can give you sufficient information in less time (and that information may not be perfectly _precise_). The practical one can give you the information that matters and will be very precise. Good link though
**edit** Made this less argumentative. My bad :)

Comment: @roliu: You are right. The theoretical results from knowing the implmentations and reasoning about time/space complexity are definitely also important - and even if you need very precise measurements, they can rule out the obviously not good enough (like O(N) in this case) and you can focus on the implementations with the same O complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the other method easier to follow, and still be fast:

```
public char SourceToDest(char c)
{
    return (char)((int)'j' - (int)c + (int)'0');
}
```

Another option is:

```
const string destination = "9876543210";
public char SourceToDest(char c)
{
    return destination[(int)c - (int)'a'];
}
```

Which will be faster than your other two methods.

Comment: The second looks different and may be faster, however all the 'abcdefghij' and '9876543210' are my supposed rule, what if the actual source collection is 'µ©Ìóî÷úûü'? The code values of characters are not contiguously ascendingly, your code will be useful only when we know the exact difference between any code values of any contiguous characters (in my example, it's 1, it can be 2, 3, 4...).

Comment: @KingKing: The second assumes that the source character values are ascending, with the difference between adjacent characters equal to 1. It doesn't matter what the destination characters are. If your source characters don't meet those criteria, then you should build a `Dictionary<char,char>` and do the lookup that way.

Comment: Yes, I can understand it (no need to be equal to 1, may be 2, 3, 4 but the code should be modified a little, dividing the subtraction by 2,3,4 respectively). Using Dictionary is OK, I think of SortedDictionary as outcoldman's suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SortedDictionary<char, char>` in your case. Search in `SortedDictionary` is `O(log n)`. Search in string with `IndexOf` I guess should be `O(n)`, I don't think that it has some special optimizations (at least MSDN does not tell you that). So your example will be

```
SortedDictionary<char, char> encoding = new SortedDictionary<char, char>()
                       {
                         { 'a', '9' }, { 'b', '8' } /* ... */ , { 'j', '0' }
                       }

public char SourceToDest(char c){
    return encoding[c];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. I think I would like to use it for my method. (my table has only 256 entries, however I have to call this method many times like placing it in another loop)

Comment: Why not a normal Dictionary? It has outperformed a SortedDictionary in any test I've ever seen

Comment: Search in `Dictionary` is `O(n)`, `SortedDictionary` has `O(log n)`. But insert should be faster in `Dictionary`. So it depends on the case.

Comment: That's all very well, but Dictionary is faster in practice. The O(n) only happens when the hash function is broken.

Comment: I think SortedDictionary is faster when reading, all the values are inserted (for example in some internal binary tree), to do the insertion, it will need more time, however it will help search for values faster because of the internal binary tree (I'm not sure if there is an internal binary tree but it's something like that). Dictionary will be faster when inserting of course, maybe you harold have made insertion most of the time with Dictionary.

Comment: `Dictionary<char,char>` will be faster than `SortedDictionary<char,char>`. Dictionary lookup is O(1) when the hash function is reasonable, and I know that the hash function for `char` is good.

Comment: @JimMischel do you mean Dictionary is better than SortedDictionary because of the key being type of char? I'm glad to know that. Thanks!

Comment: No, `Dictionary` is in general better than `SortedDictionary` because `Dictionary` has O(1) insertion, removal, and lookup (provided you have a good hash function). `SortedDictionary` has O(log n) insertion, removal, and lookup. *In general* `Dictionary` is the thing to use if you want to look things up by key.

Answer (score 0):

In general for large(r) string lengths N, the first will be O(N) by virtue of being a linear search, while the second will be O(1) as a indexed access.

For small(er) string lengths N the asymptotic performance is swamped by the constant factor, and you would have to measure hundreds of millions of accesses to get e meaningful comparison. But would you even care in these cases? Surely there are dozens of more productive performance cases to investigate in the application.